# How to move Form submit buttons closer

Tags: php, html

I have the following scripts placed in my PHP page:

```
echo "The file has been successfully read!";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<form action='displaypurchase.php' method='post' target='_blank' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='Password' value='" . $_POST['Password'] . "'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='displaypurchase' value='Purchases'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<form action='displaygamebucks.php' method='post' target='_blank' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='Password' value='" . $_POST['Password'] . "'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='displaygamebucks' value='Gamebucks'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<form action='main.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='Password' value='" . $_POST['Password'] . "'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='returntomain' value='Back to main'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<br>";
```

The page look's like this:

http://s16.postimg.org/6afeiln85/Capture.png

As you can see, the form buttons are far from each other. I wanted them to align vertically and closer to each other. How do I achieve his? I tried float but the result was a mess.

EDIT:

Here's what I have so far. I added CSS style inside the FORM tag as Kel suggested.

now I'm getting this:

http://s30.postimg.org/4fa5mxpxd/Capture2.png

It's almost there, as you can see it's already closed to each other, the only problem left is I want them positioned vertically, meaning from top to bottom. The picture shows they are positioned from top to bottom but each buttons are moving to the right. I needed the 
 tags since without it, the buttons would line up horizontally.

FINAL EDIT:
Got it to work the way I want it to be. I don't know why I haven't thought of it before, but I used a table without borders, and it worked exactly as how I wanted it to be. Posting an answer to help others

Comment: Remove all three `echo "<br>";` after `echo "</from>";` and then use `CSS` `form {float: left;}` http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/xHAsg/

Comment: Sorry, new here. Where do I add that CSS code in a PHP page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use that much echo.
Try this code hop your problem will be fixed and the code will be much more cleaner.

```
<?php
$password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['Password']);    // it's your decision how you will get data from user 

$forms= <<<DATA
<style>
    form{
        float:left;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<form action='displaypurchase.php' method='post' target='_blank' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='Password' value="{$password}" />
    <input type='submit' name='displaypurchase' value='Purchases'>
</form>


<form action='displaygamebucks.php' method='post' target='_blank' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='Password' value="{$password}">
    <input type='submit' name='displaygamebucks' value='Gamebucks'>
</form>


<form action='main.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='Password' value="{$password}">
    <input type='submit' name='returntomain' value='Back to main'>
</form>
DATA;

echo $forms;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float inside a div

```
 .rows
 {
  float:left;
 }

   <div>The file has been successfully read!</div>
  <div class="rows">
  <form action='displaypurchase.php' method='post' target='_blank' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='hidden' name='Password' value=''>
 <input type='submit' name='displaypurchase' value='Purchases'>
</form>
 </div>

   <div class="rows">

 <form action='displaygamebucks.php' method='post' target='_blank' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='hidden' name='Password' value=''>
 <input type='submit' name='displaygamebucks' value='Gamebucks'>
</form>
 </div>
<div class="rows">
<form action='main.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='hidden' name='Password' value=''>
<input type='submit' name='returntomain' value='Back to main'>
</form>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9qJ5/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean horizontally instead of vertically? If so remove the `<br>` and add some CSS for the forms to `display: inline-block;`

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/CVfNx/

Comment: No, sorry. I need them to line vertically since to the right will be a guide page/frame. Your jsfiddle is horizontal but it look's clean though. Where do I add that CSS? I mean I'm using a PHP page so I don't have HTML <Head> to place the CSS code

Comment: You can get rid of the <br> tags after each form and they will be vertical and close together. No CSS needed. If they still aren't you can add some inline CSS to your forms if you need to get rid of padding or margins. That would look like `<form style="[CSS Here]">`

Comment: Glad you got it the way you want. The way you could have done it with the inline CSS was like this `style="display:block;"` that takes of the full with of the line so you don't have that stair stepping issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I haven't thought of it before, but I used a table without borders, and it worked exactly as how I wanted it to be. Posting an answer to help others